# Instability of a system subject to periodic perturbation

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Consider the following 2-dimensional system
$$
\dot{x}(t) = A(t)x(t) \quad x(0)\in\mathbb{R}^2,
$$
where $A(t)$ is a 2-dimensional time-varying matrix. Suppose that the origin of the above system is an **unstable** equilibrium.

Now consider the following "perturbed" system
$$
\dot{z}(t) = (A(t)+\Delta(t))z(t) \quad z(0)\in\mathbb{R}^2,
$$
where $\Delta(t)$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix whose entries are **zero-mean periodic** functions of $t$.

> ***My question:*** Is the origin of the "perturbed" system **unstable** for every choice of $\Delta(t)$ as above?

My feeling is that the answer is no, but I couldn't find so far  an explicit counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markus and Yamabe showed that the origin in the system
$$
\dot{x}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} -1 + \frac{3}{2} \cos^2(t) & 1 - \frac{3}{2} \sin(t) \cos(t) \\ -1 - \frac{3}{2} \sin(t) \cos(t) & -1 + \frac{3}{2} \sin^2(t) \end{pmatrix} x(t)
$$
is unstable (see, e.g., p. 121 in Hale [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486472116)).  If we take
$$
A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} -1 + \frac{3}{2} \cos^2(t) & 1 - \frac{3}{2} \sin(t) \cos(t) \\ -1 - \frac{3}{2} \sin(t) \cos(t) & -1 + \frac{3}{2} \sin^2(t) \end{pmatrix}, \quad \Delta(t) = \begin{pmatrix} - \frac{3}{4} \cos(2t) & \frac{3}{4} \sin(2t) \\ \frac{3}{4} \sin(2t) & \frac{3}{4} \cos(2t) \end{pmatrix}
$$
($\Delta(t)$ has zero-mean periodic entries) then the autonomous system 
$$
\dot{z}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{4} & 1 \\ -1 & -\frac{3}{4} \end{pmatrix} z(t),
$$
having eigenvalues with negative real parts, is asymptottically stable.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps do you have also in mind a counterexample in which $\Delta(t) = f(t)C$ with $f(t)$ a periodic zero-mean scalar function and $C$ a constant $2\times 2$ matrix?

Comment: No, I don't have at the moment. It think that such problems are a staple in Control Theory, but, alas, I'm no expert.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. I think I’ll post a follow-up question concerning instability in this particular case, which looks interesting to me.