# Instability of a system subject to periodic perturbation (cont'd)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863836/instability-of-a-system-subject-to-periodic-perturbation).

Consider the following 2-dimensional system
$$
\dot{x}(t) = A(t)x(t) \quad x(0)\in\mathbb{R}^2,
$$
where $A(t)$ is a 2-dimensional time-varying matrix. Suppose that the origin of the above system is an **unstable** equilibrium.

Now consider the following "perturbed" system
$$
\dot{z}(t) = (A(t)+\delta(t)C)z(t) \quad z(0)\in\mathbb{R}^2,
$$
where $C$ is a constant $2\times 2$ matrix and $\delta(t)$ is a **zero-mean periodic** function of $t$.

> ***My question:*** Is the origin of the "perturbed" system **unstable** for every choice of $C$ and $\delta(t)$ as above?

As in my previous question, my feeling is that the answer is in the negative; finding an explicit counterexample does not seem easy though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer would be no, namely a known counter example would be a [Kapitza pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapitza%27s_pendulum). This is an inverted pendulum whose base is oscillating vertically. When linearizing at the origin the dynamics can be written as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\theta} \\ \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix} = \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ \alpha & -\beta
\end{bmatrix} + 
\sin(\omega\,t)
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ \gamma & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
\theta \\ \dot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix},
$$

where $\alpha,\beta>0$ thus $A(t)$, while actually not time varying, is unstable. For certain choices for $\omega$ and $\gamma$ this system can be made stable. For example the [system is stable](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%3D(sin(t)%2B0.2)*x-x%27) when using $\beta=\omega=\gamma=1$ and $\alpha=0.2$.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, does there exist an analytic way to check for which values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\omega$ the origin of the system is unstable?

Comment: @Ludwig I am not aware of a general analytical method. When I analyzed the stability of this system I numerically evaluated the state transition matrix after one period, after which the dynamics would repeat, so that result could be considered as discrete LTI system. So the stability could be analyzed by looking whether its eigenvalues inside the unit circle.